# Running Services on Specific Nodes with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm new to docker swarm and looking to set containers to run on a specific node in the swarm.
For example, I have the following nodes:

```
Manager
Worker1
Worker2
```

And I have a couple services listed in a compose yml similar to:

```
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    container_name: my_container_name
    networks:
      - my_network

  my_service2:
    image: my_image2
    container_name: my_container_name2
    networks:
      - my_network
```

How can I make it so that my_service only runs on Worker1 and my_service2 only runs on Worker2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I managed to find the solution. Can specify deployment constraints as shown below.

```
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    container_name: my_container_name
    networks:
      - my_network
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == Worker1

  my_service2:
    image: my_image2
    container_name: my_container_name2
    networks:
      - my_network
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == Worker2
```